# Pylint ignores disable-msg - but only dependent on other modules linted in the same go

Tags: python, pylint

I have an issue with pylint, which I suspect might be a bug, but I have difficulties in boiling it down to something ticketable, so I would like to know if others have experienced what I am experiencing, and if so, how it was solved.

At the company I work for, we have moved to lint our entire code base, which is basically done with a

```
find my_subdir -iname '*.py' | sort | xargs pylint
```

In three of the modules, say m_a, m_b and m_c, there is a violation of W0201 which cannot be avoided, and I have marked the offending lines with

# pylint: disable-msg=W0201

This works except for the first module encountered (m_a), where the directive is ignored. (It is ignored no matter if I move it to the scope of the entire method, class or module.) For modules m_b and m_c the directive takes effect.

If I delete m_a, then I get the 'ignore directive'-effect on m_b instead (and if I delete that, I get it on m_c.)
All three modules are dependent on a fourth module, say m_x, so I tried changing the command line to

```
find my_subdir -iname '*.py' | sort | grep -v 'm_x' | xargs pylint
```

and now the linting passes (i.e. the 'ignore directive'-effect does not happen.)

This all suggests to me that in Pylint there is some sort of state being carried from the check of one module to the next, but I cannot find any documentation on this. Is it known behaviour of Pylint?

If it is a bug, then I would like to help getting it resolved. Sadly the code-base is confidential and huge, so I would probably need to debug the Pylint code-base myself. Therefore, I hope someone would be so kind as to tell me where I should start looking?

EDIT: The output from pylint --version is:

`pylint 0.26.0, 
astng 0.24.1, common 0.58.3
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3]`

I have tried to reproduce the problem in a smaller scale, but so far no luck with that.

Comment: try to reproduce the pb using dumb modules that can be publicly shown?  then you may want to explain your pb on pylint mailing-list, python-projects@lists.logilab.org

Comment: can you post the output of pylint --version please?